# ReactJS props are updated, but field is not re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been playing around with fields in React, but am running into the issue where a text input is not updating (whilst the properties are). I have tried to do it through a class/state component, but to no avail. I was kind-of hoping to be able to make specific form-only components that are completely cut-off from stores. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {

    function editProjectNameChanged(event, syntheticEvent) {
        debugger;
        props.editProject.name = syntheticEvent.target.value;
    }

    return (
        <div className="col-xs-5 col-md-5">
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="management-projects-name">Project name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="management-projects-name"
                           value={props.editProject.name}
                           onUserInput={editProjectNameChanged.bind(null, event)}
                           placeholder="Project name" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance.. This whole form thing is more difficult than I thought it would!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't change the props in the child. That is a good job for the state. It's not a good idea to update props because parent component is not notified of the change and the state is more useful because when you call setState() the component is redraw. Something like that (I haven't tested it)

```
import React from 'react';

export class YourComponent extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        this.state = {
            name: this.props.editProject.name
        };
    }


    editProjectNameChanged(event, syntheticEvent) {
        this.setState({
            name: syntheticEvent.target.value
        });
    }

    render(){
        return <div className="col-xs-5 col-md-5">
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="management-projects-name">Project name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="management-projects-name"
                           value={props.editProject.name}
                           onUserInput={editProjectNameChanged.bind(this, event)}
                           placeholder="Project name" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mutate `props` the way you do it from within a component. If you do not want your component do manage the state, it should instead accept a callback as a `prop`, that it would call on user input.
The parent component would then decide whether or not, and how, to update the value, and pass it back to your component as a prop.

```
<input value={ props.value } onChange={ e => props.onChange(e.target.value) } />
```

Mutating directly the `props` object has no effect since version 0.13. You can find here the [blog post explaining why this behaviour was introduced](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/02/24/streamlining-react-elements.html)